# Answers from the OP shouldn't appear in the Late Answers queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I recently had to perform [a Late Answer review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4980292), where the answer is actually provided by the OP who originally asked the question. [From what I understand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148088/253494), the point of reviewing late answers is to:

- ensure the answer contributes to answering the question
- ensure the answer is actually an answer (not spam, or pleas for help, etc)

In my experience, an answer provided by the OP is typically a summary of what they've tried and/or the solution that ultimately solved their problem, which definitely adds contribution to the question. And since question-askers can edit their question plus comment regardless of rep, such answers are almost never spam or pleas for help (in my experience).

So, is there any reason why these answers shouldn't be filtered out from the Late Answers review queue?

Comment: There are lots of users who attempt to add additional information by posting an answer when they should be editing the question. This review queue also helps catch that behavior.

Comment: not only additional information like @CodyGray already said but some even post full follow up questions as answers.

Comment: I see. Just out of curiosity, how long does it take for a question to be considered 'old' or an answer 'late'?

Comment: I'm kind of confused what your stance on the issue is since it looks like you're supporting the OP's own answers to their questions but then wondering why they're not filtered out, but I think a late answer is a late answer regardless who made it.

Comment: @MxyL My thought was that late answers by the OP almost never brings any harm, and therefore shouldn't need to be reviewed. I'm certainly not as experienced as some of the other commenters though, who have already begun to shed some light on why reviewing such answers could catch some unwanted behavior. I'm slightly skeptical on how often such behavior happens (late answers adding more info, etc), but I wouldn't be a good judge on the matter.

Comment: @JWLim Put it that way, now your stance and the question makes sense to me. I was thinking about it from a different angle! But even then, it could be a bad answer I guess. I've seen OP answers that were "thanks guys it's been solved" maybe a month later or something...

Comment: Not only should they not appear in the late review queue, answers from the poster of the question itself should have a special display format/indicator to avoid mishandling by those who read too quickly - lots of brief answers that state how the poster resolved their problem end up getting mistakenly removed, leaving the questions permanently orphaned in an (apparently) unanswered state.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

People often post non-answers to their own questions. These usually come in the form of additional information that should have been an edit to the question, but sometimes it's a link-only answer or a simple "I give up on this, you can close my question."  This happens often enough that I think it's worth reviewing late answers by the OP.

Comment: Perhaps, but actual legitimate resolved-the-issue answers from askers often get mistakenly flagged and deleted, too.  Unfortunately, the mere fact of something being *under review* by a party who didn't find it *out of personal interest* already sets up a fairly negative bias leading to bad calls by those who read too quickly.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I see far more non-answers posted by OPs than I see good answers deleted by mistake. Those mistakes can be rolled back too.